# Checkbox loses focus with FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"

Tags: wpf, checkbox, focus

I see strange behavior with my `CheckBox` and its focus/tab order.

First some "working" code:

```
<Grid>    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="25"/>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" >
        <!--TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1"-->
        <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Content="Test"  />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="3"/>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

If you try this, the tab order works fine - as long as you do not check the CheckBox. If I check the CheckBox it loses focus and the next tab press sets the focus to the Button.

If I remove `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` all works fine.

My question is this behavior wanted or a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is somehow expected. In order to fix it, you can add a handler for GotFocus on the window.

Assuming your check box is named chkBox, something like this:

```
protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);

     if (e.Source == chkBox)
         FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, chkBox); 

}
```

This problem and some similar ones are discussed in more detail in [this msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f5de6ffc-fa03-4f08-87e9-77bbad752033/).

Comment: this would work. but i still wondering why this just happen for the checkbox an no other input controls.

Comment: It will also happen for other controls like RadioButton, have a look at Weifen Luo answer in the linked msdn thread, it has a nice explanation on why this happens.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to bypass built-in functionality by shadowing the default `<InputBindings>` with custom ones, e.g. `<KeyBinding Key="Space" Command="{Binding ToggleInVmCommand}"`/>